# Create bootable sd card with parted

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, parted

I executed the following script to create a bootable SD card, but the raspberry pi doesn't boot. The sd cards are fine, they arrived today in the mail and badblocks found none. What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
sudo parted --script /dev/sdb \
    mklabel msdos \
    mkpart primary fat32 1MiB 256MiB \
    mkpart primary ext4 256MiB 100% \
    set 1 boot on \
    set 1 lba on
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb2
```

Edit: I checked the output of parted print and fdisk -l here are the results, they look fine to me.

The result if I execute fdisk -l is

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 29.8 GiB, 32010928128 bytes, 62521344 sectors
Disk model: SD/MMC/MS PRO   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x93bfb447

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      2048   524287   522240  255M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2       524288 62521343 61997056 29.6G 83 Linux
```

The output of parted is

```
Model: Generic- SD/MMC/MS PRO (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  268MB   267MB   primary               boot, lba
 2      268MB   32.0GB  31.7GB  primary  ext4
```

Edit: I follow this guide on the Alpine Wiki: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Classic_install_or_sys_mode_on_Raspberry_Pi#Preparation

Edit: I made some progress on trying. If I run the following script and copy the files it will boot.

```
sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sdb -I
```

Comment: Are you following some instructions to make the bootable SD card? You've formatted the SD card but not yet installed the bootloader or OS, it seems.

Comment: I do follow the instructions of the alpine wiki. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The script was completely fine. My sd card reader was a bit jacked after using a card with a ton of bad blocks.